# In Google Sheets, using script to create Forms, need to add trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using script to create new sheets and corresponding forms & form response sheets.  That all works.  I know I can go to each Form individually and add a trigger, but I would like to add it with the script as I create them.  I assume there should be something like FormApp.setTrigger or similar.

```js
function createForm(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var listClean = sh.getRange(3,1,100,1).getvalues();
 
 var form = FormApp.create(sheetName);
  form.setTitle(sheetName);
  form.addCheckboxGridItem()
      .setColumns(['Approved', 'Not Approved'])
      .setRows(listClean);
   form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());

  form.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you for your assistance.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are created using `ScriptApp`. You can view the documentation for

- managing triggers programmatically [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)
- `FormTriggerBuilder` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder)
- event objects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)

Example:

```
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
     .forForm(form)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
```

Also note that if you want a trigger that uses the *response data*, then you need to use the `SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onformsubmit)) and the Google Sheets [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).